# WKWebView tapping on a ad doesn't fire delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using a `WKWebView` and I have the delegate methods for navigation (request/response) and everything works as it should. For some reason, there are some ads that the function doesn't fire at all. Any idea why? I can't even check the URL to see what is happening.

I get only `WKContentView[@] set up: @ pid: @ MACH_PORT` 
and on the simulator if get a pop-up menu with title :
**JavaScript** and options : **open / cancel**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

can I use something in configure?

Thanks

Comment: You can add observer `webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)` and then `override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {print(change?[.newKey],change?[.oldKey])}`

Comment: it doesn't get triggered the observer for some reason and I tried different solutions to make it triggered

Comment: @canister_exister I managed to get the url with a similar solution so thanks for the  help man. Now I just have to figure out why it is not firing the delegate method.

Comment: decidePolicyFor not always working for redirects

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should put something into the method where you set in the HTML files which named window.webkit.messageHandlers.yourMethodName.postMessage("something")